# What is produce and consume in @Request Mapping

Tags: java, spring

I have the following line of code in my project.

```
@RequestMapping(value = UrlHandler.GET_AUTHENTICATION, 
    produces = {"application/json"}, 
    consumes = {"application/json"}, 
    method = RequestMethod.POST
)
```

What is this `produces` and `consumes` meaning in the above lines.

Comment: edit your question and format your code

Answer (score 12):

The code is made for RESTful APIs, which means *Representational State Transfer*, in another words your representational data can change as per the request made to them.

For example if the client request for data in the XML format it will negotiate the content like

```
consumes = {"application/xml"}
```

Or if it wants data in JSON it will negotiate content like this:

```
consumes = {"application/json"}
```

On the server side you can have both the statement as

```
produces = {"application/json"}
```

or

```
produces = {"application/xml"}
```

This means that your service can generate data in XML or JSON as per what client has requested. This is part of content *negotiation*. In HTTP network calls, you can change the Header value to get different representation of same data thanks to REST.

The code mentioned by you states that, it will take JSON data and will produce JSON data.

Answer (score 6):

It specifies the supported media type of the request (consumes), and the media type of the response (produces).

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--

Answer (score 1):

Simple - Every request has an Input & Output. (Void sometimes means empty)

The data types ('http media type') related to the inputs are Consumes & output are Produces.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, you can say what server expects and what you send.
Say server API expects application/JSON response and you send application/x-www-form-urlencoded then it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

For a RESTful endpoint, `produces` means the media type that I return as response. It basically sets `Content-Type` header if you use HTTP as protocol

`consumes` means the media type that the endpoint could accept as request. In your example also JSON. It basically sets `Accept` header if you use HTTP as protocol.