# Spring Boot returning error Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: javascript, spring, fetch

I'm trying to send a POST from my javascript file to a server local host which will validate the login.

Here is my front end code:

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WorkSoftManager - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleLogin.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>WorkSoftManager</h1>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form id="login-form">
        <input type="email" id="username" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <p>Don't have an account? <a href="signUp.html">Sign Up</a></p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
// Create a function to handle the login process
async function login(username, password) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login/', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              'username' : username,
              'password': password
            })
        });

  
      // Check if the response was successful
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Login failed. Please try again.');
      }
  
      // Parse the response JSON data
      const data = await response.json();
  
      // Check if the authentication was successful
      if (!data.authenticated) {
        throw new Error('Invalid username or password.');
      }
  
      // Store the authentication token in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
  
      // Redirect the user to the loginPage.html page
      window.location.href = '/loginPage.html';
    } catch (error) {
      // Show an error message
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }

  
  // Attach an event listener to the login form submit button
  document.getElementById('login-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    // Get the values of the username and password inputs
    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  
    // Call the login function with the username and password
    login(username, password);
  });
  

  // Create a function to handle the log off process
    function logOff() {
        // Remove the authentication token from local storage
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    
        // Redirect the user to the login page
        window.location.href = '/loginPage.html';
    }
  
  // Attach an event listener to the log off link
  //document.getElementById('log-off-link').addEventListener('click', logOff);
```

#### Spring REST Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WSMController {

    private Map<String, UserSession> sessions = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private WSMService service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        User user = authenticate(request);
        if (user == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid username or password");
        }
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        UserSession session = new UserSession(user, token);
        sessions.put(token, session);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }

    @PostMapping("/logoff")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logoff(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) {
        sessions.remove(token.substring(7));
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User logged off successfully");
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public User getUser(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) {
        UserSession session = sessions.get(token.substring(7));
        if (session == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return session.getUser();
    }

    private User authenticate(LoginRequest request) {
        if(!service.getCredentials(request)) {
            return null;
        }

        return new User(request.getUsername(),request.getPassword());
    }
```

#### LoginRequest DTO

```java
package com.worksoftmanager.WorkSoftManagerAuthenticator.model;

public class LoginRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message from server side:

```
2023-02-06 10:43:10.674  WARN 20380 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

I've tried set the headers to send an `application/json` content and change the `RequestMapping` to consume `Application_JSON_Value`, but none of it worked.

---------Testing response-----------:

----John's response:

[image]

After I make the request, I got this message on console:

[image]

Error using await response.json()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSvVy.png)

----David's response:

Headers:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9yGm.png)

Body:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqyz8.png)

Comment: What does your LoginRequest class look like?

Comment: Let me edit my question by adding the LoginRequest @AchoVasilev

Comment: If the response from the server is a token (string), what are you calling: `const data = await response.json()`, shouldn't it be: `const token = await response.text()`? There should be no issue with the `POST` logic, just the response handling. Looks like a client/XHR/JavaScript issue.

Comment: well this might me an issue in the future, but right now, the server are not sending a response, as the error of media type is being triggered on server side, probably I'll have to handle the response in front end as you mentioned @Mr.Polywhirl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@PostMapping` or other mappings can be set to specific input/output ContentTypes

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") 
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity;
}
```

Other references to understand Spring @PostMapping:

[(Baeldung) @RequestMapping Consumes and Produces](https://What%20is%20produce%20and%20consume%20in%20@Request%20Mapping)

[(Stackoverflow) What is produce and consume in @Request Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591574/what-is-produce-and-consume-in-request-mapping)

For the JavaScript part.
The problem is with `mode: 'no-cors'`

[JavaScript no-cors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837819/9085392)

A way to get arround with that is changing the java:
[JSON to Java Object](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login", consumes = "text/plain", produces = "application/json") 
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody String request) {
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
LoginRequest loginRequest = objectMapper.readValue(json, LoginRequest.class);
    ...
    return ResponseEntity;
}
```

Comment: hey, just changed the postMapping with the values you mentioned, but unfortunately I got the same error: 2023-02-06 11:29:38.765  WARN 19340 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Comment: @GustavoFarias Is there a way you can print the raw request you are doing at the JavaScript?

Comment: I've added on the question :)

Comment: @GustavoFarias If you execute the code on a browser, at the F12 Network you can see the request, with the requestHeaders and body, could you print that?

Comment: sure thing! will add in the end of my question

Comment: @GustavoFarias Thanks, as you can see at the headers you are sending is text/plain and not application/json.
So the JS is not sending the Content-Type correctly

Comment: @GustavoFarias Try again with this headers: 

headers: {

  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',

},

Comment: hey! just updated with the new headers, but the request still remains text/plain, is there another way to change it to application/json?

Comment: find out something, using no-cors, I'm unable to set the context to application/json, it will remain as text-plain

Comment: @GustavoFarias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data
The other way is expecting a String in Java and converting it with Object mapper as shown on this post: 
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @GustavoFarias Solved?

Comment: yes sir! all these analyses helped me to fix my code issue, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I think that the JSON isn't good. Try

```
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'username' : username,
      'password': password
    })
```

Also the `mode: 'no-cors'` will force the content-type to text. Either take it out or set `mode: 'cors'` - see [no-cors breaks content-type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372834/request-header-not-set-as-expected-when-using-no-cors-mode-with-fetch-api)

Comment: hey, that was a good fix, but the error is still remaining unfortunately :(

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is in the client. Can you try to point the client to fetch('http://httpbin/post and do a console.log('data', data) on the line after const data = await response.json(); Paste it in your question.

Comment: hey John, I've updated the code and get the console.log response, it is on my question in the last part

Comment: You left out the await in const data = await response.json();

Comment: If I left the await, the error will be the same, the difference is that the catch will atert the error on the browser

Comment: If you leave the await out you will get a Promise from response.json(), as your screen capture shows. I need to see the data indside the Promise (hence await) that httpbin.org/post returns because that may show a problem with the call.

Comment: alright, will test with await, but quick question, I'm not a Front end person, so sorry for the dummy question, how the console.log will show the data if the catch was trigger and the alert of error just showed up?

Comment: Are you saying that const data = await response.json() to httpbin.org/post is throwing error?

Comment: yes sir! I'll attach the image of the debug on the question, hold on, updated

Comment: please uncomment everything you have but remove the mode: 'no-cors', in the fetch. I have made the same call and put the console in my answer

Comment: great, I could see the response from httpbin request, I made a quick test, calling to my server on local host I could see that the headers that are being passed to the endpoint is text-plain, which is giving me an error, I've attached the imaged on the question as well, David asked me to

Comment: find out something, using no-cors, I'm unable to set the context to application/json, it will remain as text-plain

Comment: yes - I have updated answer to reflect this